Using a mutex to stop start/stop multiple threads running the same function
My goal is this:
I want to have multiple threads running the same function, the function is a while(1) loop so it just goes on. At some point main should use a mutex to force all threads to block until main (or something else) signals them to continue at which point they all continue until they get forced to block them.
The threads should run in parallel
I have tried to use pthread_cond_wait() for the threads to wait and pthread_cond_broadcast() to let them continue but it does not work at all
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_mutex_t mtx;
pthread_cond_t cv;

void* func(void* arg) {
    while (1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
        pthread_cond_wait(&cv, &mtx);

        printf("Thread %lu is running.\n", pthread_self());
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);

        usleep(500000);
    }
}

int main() {
    pthread_t threads[2];

    pthread_mutex_init(&mtx, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&cv, NULL);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, func, NULL);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&cv);

    sleep(2);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    
    sleep(2);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&cv);
    sleep(2);

    return 0;
}



You are not using the condition variable correctly. First, pthread_cond_t only signals that the state might have changed, but you need an actual piece of state (a boolean variable or whatever) to hold the state. Look up "spurious wake up". Second, you need to lock the mutex before changing the state in the main thread. The most common pattern is lock-modify-broadcast-unlock in the signalling thread.

Did you mean for your main() to lock the mutex before creating the threads?  As it is, main() unlocks the mutex when it does not hold it locked, which is invalid.  Only the thread, if any, that currently has the mutex locked is permitted to unlock it.

You are not checking the return values of your function calls for error codes.  Your function calls failing would be a plausible explanation for the appearance that "it does not work at all".

A mutex is useful in a scenario where you want exactly one thread to be able to access a give section of code (or in the case of a semaphore, where you want some fixed number of threads to enter a given section of code).
That's not what your use case asks for: you can have an infinite number of threads inside your "critical section" of your while loop, you just want a way of communicating to all of them that they should stop.
Your specific use case should decide your solution, but there are a couple ways you could proceed:

You might want to consider a reader-writer lock: this is a lock that rather than just lock and unlock methods, offers readLock, readUnlock, writeLock, and writeUnlock methods and operates under the premise that any number of readers can hold the lock at a time, but a reader cannot hold the lock any time that a writer can hold it. So in your example, the start of each while loop would be a call to lock.readLock(), with a call to lock.readUnlock() at the end of the loop, and when your main function wants to stop all the threads, it would call writeLock.lock().
A much simpler solution would be a single atomic variable should_wait that each thread will spin on:

   // start of your while(1) loop
   while(should_wait.load());


and the main function will set to true or false. As this can lead to a lot of contention between the threads you could also have one of these for each thread (for N threads you might have an array of N boolean flags where each thread will spin on its own bool variable). As this kind of busy wait is generally only practical if the wait time will be short, you might want to introduce some kind of backoff:
    // start of your while(1) loop
    
    while(should_wait.load())
    {
        backoff();
    }
    reset_backoff();


Where backoff is a per thread state that chooses some random time between MIN_WAIT and MAX_WAIT to sleep for each time it is called, and each call it doubles MAX_WAIT. Certainly the rabbit hole on other ways to wait more efficiently goes very deep, but this approach isn't unreasonable.
Also note that if you need no thread to be in the critical section, you should have some sort of counter of threads in the while loop that each thread will operate on, as something like:
    // main function
    should_wait.store(true);
    // do work that assumes all threads are waiting

will not work in the case of a thread that entered the critical section before you set the waiting flag. I'll note that this is essentially a readWrite lock.

Mutex + CV is the Swiss Army Knife of synchronization. That combination can do pretty much any synchronization job.  A reader / writer lock is an interesting idea, but it doesn't do the job that it looks like the OP wants: to make all the worker threads synchronize at the top of the loop in function.  A barrier could do that (and pthreads has a barrier implementation), but it is also fairly easy to build your own barrier with mutex + CV (c.f. "Swiss Army Knife"), which can be more flexible.

The proper use of a condition variable is to support threads and / or processes suspending execution, if necessary, until some computable condition is satisfied, which necessarily become the case through action of a different thread.  Thus,

there is always a predicate to be tested as a condition for waiting on a CV, and
that predicate must be re-tested after the wait to determine whether to proceed or to wait more.

Furthermore, at least some of the data contributing to the evaluation of the predicate must be shared among threads in order for that to work, and those data must either be atomic or (more typically) protected via the same mutex that is associated with the CV.
That might play out like so:
static _Bool can_continue = 1;

// ...

void *func(void* arg) {
    while (1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
        while (!can_continue) {            // test the predicate
            pthread_cond_wait(&cv, &mtx);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);

        // do something ...
    }
}

int main(void) {
    // ...

    // Make threads stop when they next reach the top of the loop
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    can_continue = 0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);

    // ... do something ...

    // Allow threads to continue
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    can_continue = 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&cv);

    // ... do something ...
}

Note well that like most library functions, the pthreads functions can fail. To be robust, programs need to check for such failures, every time, unless you don't care whether the function succeeds.  For clarity, I have omitted such tests from the above sample code, but any real program should include them.
That simple variation allows the threads running func() to iterate any number of times (and not necessarily the same number for each thread) before being stopped, and they only stop when they reach condition check at the top of the loop.  If you want stronger synchronization, such as threads performing only one iteration each before being allowed to continue, then you'll need to build something a little more complex, but mutex + CV is still a good tool for doing that.  On the other hand, if it happens to serve your particular purpose, then you might find a pthreads barrier convenient.

Great answer. I would just add that after the main thread sets can_continue to zero, if it needs to wait for the other threads to reach the hold point before doing whatever it needs to do, then further synchronisation will be required (the original question is underspecified in this regard).
